# Set y-axis limits and tick marks in R latticeExtra DoubleYscale plot?

Tags: r

How do I set y-axis limits and tick marks in a R latticeExtra DoubleYscale plot?  I want the primary and secondary y-axis scales and tick marks to be the same in both xyplots.  Below is my R code.  Currently, in plot 1, the primary y-scale is from -3 to 0 and the secondary y-scale is from -150 to 0.  In plot 2, the primary y-scale is from -2 to 0 and the secondary y-scale is from -200 to 0.
I want a primary y-scale is from -3 to 0 and secondary y-scale is from -200 to 0 for BOTH plots, with ability to set the number of ticks in both plots. Thanks.

```
#load workspace stol and stoh
library(latticeExtra)
library(gridExtra)
plot1<-xyplot(percentloss*100 ~ time, groups=cap, pch=16,axis = axis.grid,
abline=c(list(h=c(0,-0.5,-1,-1.5,-2,-2.5,-3)),trellis.par.get("reference.line")),
main="Storage; 5 mL fill vol",
xlab="Time (hours)",
ylab="Evaporative loss (%)" ,
auto.key=list(border=TRUE), 
par.settings = simpleTheme(pch=16), scales=list(x=list(relation='same'), 
y=list(relation='same')),
data=stol)
plot2<-xyplot(absoluteloss*1000 ~ time, groups=cap, pch=16,
main="    ",
xlab="Time (hours)",
ylab="Absolute loss (uL)" ,
 data=stol)
plota<-doubleYScale(plot1, plot2, style1 = 0, style2 = 0, add.ylab2 = T)
plot3<-xyplot(percentloss*100 ~ time, groups=cap, pch=16,axis = axis.grid,
abline=c(list(h=c(0,-0.5,-1,-1.5,-2,-2.5,-3)),trellis.par.get("reference.line")),
main="Storage; 10 mL fill vol",
xlab="Time (hours)",
ylab="Evaporative loss (%)" ,
auto.key=list(border=TRUE), 
par.settings = simpleTheme(pch=16), scales=list(x=list(relation='same'), 
y=list(relation='same')),
data=stoh)
plot4<-xyplot(absoluteloss*1000 ~ time, groups=cap, pch=16,
main="    ",
xlab="Time (hours)",
ylab="Absolute loss (uL)" ,
data=stoh)
plotb<-doubleYScale(plot3, plot4, style1 = 0, style2 = 0, add.ylab2 = T)
grid.arrange(plota,plotb, ncol=2)
```